# Firestore get field value with document ref

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "doctors" with fields like name, id, username...

Inside doctors there is a field "medicalcenter" that has a reference to the collection named "medicalcenters" with fields like address and name of the medical center...

What I want is. When I get a list of doctors I want also to get the medical center name with this document reference that I have inside the doctors collection.

doc.data().medicalcenter inside doctors collections has the reference.

```
getdoctors () {
  firebase.firestore().collection('doctor').orderBy('id').get().then(result => {
    result.forEach(doc => {
      const data = {
        'id': doc.data().id,
        'nome': doc.data().nome,
        'email': doc.data().email,
        'username': doc.data().username
        'medicalcenter': HERE I WANT THE MEDICAL CENTER NAME
      }
      this.items.push(data)
    })
  })
}
```

How is it possible to make this happens?

How can I get the specific collcetion and the field name using the collection reference stored in the doctors?

Do I have to user 2 methods Async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to create this function.
The getDoctor async function will wait the await medicalcenter.
This way I can get the medical center that each doctor works.

```
  created () {
    this.getdoctors()
  },
  methods: {
    getdoctors: async function () {
      try {
        let result = await firebase.firestore().collection('doctor').get()
        result.forEach(async doc => {
        console.log(doc.data())
        var medicalcenter = await firebase.firestore().collection('medicalcenter').doc(doc.data().centrosaude.id).get()
          const data = {
            'id': doc.data().id,
            'nome': doc.data().nome,
            'email': doc.data().email,
            'centrosaude': medicalcenter.data().nome
          }
        this.items.push(data)
       })
     } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider denormalising your data.  Rather than saving only the medical center ref and performing joins, consider saving the ref AND the name, so that you only need to do one query. If the medical center name changes, you can trigger a cloud function to change the name in all doctor documents.

It's much easier to create a data model for something that you'll do many times, than something that may happen rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to make another query for each other document in medicalcenters in order to effectively "join" all this data into a single object.  You'll need to manage your promises correctly so that the final result is complete only after all the queries are complete for all the doctors and medical centers.